# How to substitute the same capturing group multiple, uncertain number of times?

Tags: regex

Sorry for the title, but I couldn't find a way to phrase is better. What I have is a structure that looks like this (size of every indented group is artbitrary, as is the size of fillers between them):

```
q
111:
    a
    b
    c
w
e
222:
    d
    e
    f
    g
r
```

I want to convert it to look like this:

```
q
111: a
111: b
111: c
w
e
222: d
222: e
222: f
222: g
r
```

What I'm currently doing right now is this: 1) Search for the last tab of each indented group and replace it with the 'header'; 2) Repeat the whole process once per item in the largest indented group; 3) Manually remove the headers. Needless to say, this feels very much like a hack. This is the regex I'm using for the first step: `^([^\n]*:)(.*?)\t(?![^\n]*?\n\t) → \1\2\1[ ]`
What I'd really like is to replace all the tabs in every indented group at once, but I cannot find any way to do this. I'm using Python's re (or rather a Sublime Text regex plugin that uses this library).

Comment: Can you process this with another tool? Maybe `awk`. I don't know if regex is the best tool for the job here.

Comment: There's no looping in regexp replace. Use a better tool, as @wcarroll suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if regex is the best tool to use here. I would use a more pointed text-processing tool like `awk`.

```
{
  if (match($0, /^[0-9]+:$/)) {
    num = $1;
  }
  else if(match($0, /^[ ]+[a-z]$/)) {
    print num, $NF;
  }
  else {
    print $0;
  }
}
```

You can run it like this:

```
$ awk -f /tmp/script.awk </tmp/file.ext
```

Output:

```
q
111: a
111: b
111: c
w
e
222: d
222: e
222: f
222: g
r
```

Where `script.awk` is the above snippet and `file.ext` is the file that you need to process.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python, then an alternative could be to just loop over the lines and build up your result:

```
import re

res = []
key = ''
for s in input.splitlines():
    if s.endswith(':'):
        key = s
    else:
        res.append(re.sub('^\\t', key, s))
res = '\n'.join(res)

print(res)
```